# Fill the current time based on the selection of the country in html dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, python, html

I have an HTML drop-down where country names are specified.And there is another field where a date time field is specified.

When a user selects a country i want the date-time field to be filled with current date-time of that particular country.Please let me know in what all ways this can be done and how.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May be `moment.js`.....`moment timezone`...

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to get the country name of the select tag with `$( "#myselect option:selected" ).text();` or it's value  with `$( "#myselect" ).val();` and then use a switch statement to change the date time field.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: List all the time zones using,

```
$timezone_identifiers = DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers();
for ($i=0; $i < 20; $i++) {
    echo "$timezone_identifiers[$i]";
}
```

Step 2: Get the time for that specific time zone,

```
date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Algiersn');
echo $date= date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Ref: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.listidentifiers.php

Comment: Can you let me know how i can add this to the page where the country be specified by user based on that date-time can be filled

Comment: @user5358888 u have specific countries in dropdown or u want to display list of all countries.

Comment: @user5358888 So in that case you will have to search the required time zones from `timezone_identifiers `  and list them accordingly in your drop down.

Comment: @user5358888 just select the required timezones from this list `echo "$timezone_identifiers[$i]";` and then add it to your `select` dropdown.